# Can hard drives experience magnetic interference from a server chassis?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm currently building a server, and it's exhibiting the weirdest behavior with the hard drive.  It is a 2U case, and I have trouble trouble accessing the Seagate SATAIII hard drive when it is in the bottom slot of the hard drive cage.  The case is made of galvanized/anodized steel.  I thought the drive was DOA, but then I swapped it into the top slot, and the problem was solved--the system had no trouble recognizing the drive anymore!

This got me thinking: Is it possible that the magnetic field from the chassis was affecting the hard drive's functionality?  I only have this problem with the mechanical hard drive, not the SSD.  Could it be because the chassis is made of steel?  I'm baffled.

Comment: Are the cables and screws the same?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When you moved the drive, did you use the same screws and cables as when it was in the other bay?

Comment: Yes, identical.

Comment: The metal case should be tied to earth ground, i.e. the ground (third) prong of the power plug or the green wire with a yellow stripe of the power cord.  Or more often with PC cases, the case is grounded through contact with the PSU.  With everything disconnected from the AC line, verify that there is continuity between the case and ground prong.

Comment: I believe the case is tied to ground fine.  I have it screwed into the chassis.

Comment: Cable possibly has a short and only works when it has a curve in it, or whatever shape it takes when it is up top. Try another cable and see if problem continues.

Comment: @ekaj *"Cable possibly has a short"*  A "short"? That would cause smoke to be released and/or blowing a fuse!  Or do you mean an **open** as in "open circuit"?  Or do you like to use "short" as a general purpose term for "electrical problem"?

Answer (score 1):

Check the data cable.  At least in my PC, the very bottom slot would force me to bend the cable near the drive at a bit of a hard angle.  Perhaps this is causing a disconnect on one of the contacts.

For that matter, the power cable could cause it as well.

Comment: I really think it might be the power cable.  I realized that it looks like the connectors in the middle of the cable receive power through what looks somewhat like a T-tap connection.  Those connections have always failed me in the past.  I'm dedicating a new SATA power cable specifically for this hard drive, and I'll report back.